# Invalid object name 'ItemList' .Error RD = RC.ExecuteReader

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012

Please help me, the error is Itemlist is invalid name but still have in my sql server 2012 database, and if i will run the pin point will point to executereader.

```
Private Sub IBarcode_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles IBarcode.KeyPress

    If e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Enter) Then

        Conn.Open()

        RC = New SqlCommand
        RC.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IBarcode", IBarcode.Text)

        SQL = "Select ItemDesc from ItemList where IBarcode = @IBarcode"
        RC.CommandText = SQL
        RC.Connection = Conn

        RD = RC.ExecuteReader

        If RD.Read Then

            ItemName.Text = RD("ItemDesc")

        Else

            MsgBox("Item not found on the Database")
            IBarcode.Focus()
            IBarcode.SelectAll()

        End If

        RD.Close()
        Conn.Close()

        RC = Nothing

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If the error message says that there is no such table then there is no such table. If you think there is then you must be looking at a different database. If there really is such a table in the database that you're connecting to then your system is corrupted somehow, which is a different issue altogether and not for SO.

Comment: What I need to do sir?

Comment: You've already been told what to do.  1) verify that the database structure is what you expect (ItemList is in DB) 2) Verify that you are connecting to the right database

Comment: Side notes: this code has some serious issues. You are clearly not using `Option Explicit On` and `Option Strict On` which you should *always* do in VB. Do not cache connection objects, create a new one when you need it. Dispose connection, command and reader with `Using` blocks. Setting `RC = Nothing` doesn't do anything, just dispose as mentioned. [Don't use `AddWithValue`](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), specify parameter types and lengths explicitly. Don't block the thread with a `MessageBox` while the connection is open.